# How do I get the Visual Studio "Open Command Line" to open the Git Shell installed by GitHub for Windows?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github-for-windows

You need to get powershell to run a couple of scripts on startup to initialise the shell in the same way as clicking the "Git Shell" shortcut installed by GitHub for Windows. You can do this via the -command command-line argument supplied to powershell.exe

This can be done as follows:

Open Tools > Options > Environment / Command Line

Set Command to: powershell.exe

Set Command Arguments to the following (single line):

-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -Command .(Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1"); .(Resolve-Path "$env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1")

Answer (score 0):

**Remember:** Github installs [`posh-git`](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) for you. You have the option to run the `posh-git` on every shell. You would just setup your default ps1 for the Environment.

#### Disclaimer:

[Make sure you have minimum requirements for `posh-git`](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installing-manual)

- specifically `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

The following solution was tested on `x64` - `Win7` and `Win8.1`

You will be setting up your files in:

```
PS> cd $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell
```

#### To run a Git Shell on each Powershell environment

Create a file `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` In `$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` dir

With contents: (Make sure the path to `poshgit` is correct)

```
# Load posh-git example profile
. 'C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-869d4c5\profile.example.ps1'

Rename-Item Function:\Prompt PoshGitPrompt -Force
function Prompt() {if(Test-Path Function:\PrePoshGitPrompt){++$global:poshScope; New-Item function:\script:Write-host -value "param([object] `$object, `$backgroundColor, `$foregroundColor, [switch] `$nonewline) " -Force | Out-Null;$private:p = PrePoshGitPrompt; if(--$global:poshScope -eq 0) {Remove-Item function:\Write-Host -Force}}PoshGitPrompt}
```

Make sure the `GitHub.PowerShell_profile.ps1` is also in `$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`

```
# If Posh-Git environment is defined, load it.
if (test-path env:posh_git) {
    . $env:posh_git
}
```

#### shell command (x86)

```
%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

#### shell command (x64)

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

#### Command to check `x64` vs `x86`

PS> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess